# Is $\displaystyle {{f(x_{0} + h ) - 2 f(x_{0} + h/2 ) +f(x_{0} )} \over {h^2 / 4}} - f^{(2)}(x_{0}) = O(h^2) $ true??

Tags: analysis

$\displaystyle {{f(x_{0} + h ) - 2 f(x_{0} + h/2 ) +f(x_{0} )} \over {h^2 / 4}} - f^{(2)}(x_{0}) = O(h^2) $ 
Is it true?

I think, using taylor expansion,

$(a)$ : $\displaystyle f(x_{0} + h) = f(x_{0}) + h f'(x_{0}) + {{h^2} \over {2}} f''(x_{0})  + {{h^3} \over {6}} f^{(3)} (x_{0}) + O(h^4)  $

$(b)$ : $\displaystyle f(x_{0} + h/2) = f(x_{0}) + {{h} \over {2}} f'(x_{0}) + {{h^2} \over {8}} f''(x_{0}) + {{h^3} \over {24}} f^{(3)} (x_{0}) + O(h^4)  $

$2(b)$ : $ \displaystyle 2f(x_{0} + h/2) = 2f(x_{0}) + h f'(x_{0}) + {{h^2} \over {4}} f''(x_{0}) + {{h^3} \over {12}} f^{(3)} (x_{0}) + O(h^4)  $

Subtracting $2(b)$ from $(a)$,

$\displaystyle f(x_{0} + h) - 2f(x_{0} + h/2) = - f(x_{0}) + {{h^2} \over {4}} f''(x_{0})  + {{h^3} \over {12}} f^{(3)} (x_{0}) + O(h^4)  $
$\displaystyle \implies {{f(x_{0} + h ) - 2 f(x_{0} + h/2 ) +f(x_{0} )} \over {h^2 / 4}} - f''(x_{0})= {{h} \over {3}} f^{(3)} (x_{0}) + O(h^4) = O(h)$

How can i drive $O(h^2)$ ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever you have done is right and the statement is false. For a counter-example just make sure that $f'''(x_0) \neq 0$. One simple example: $f(x)=x^{3}$ and $x_0 =0$. Here the exact value of the expression is $3h$ which is not $O(h^{2})$.

Comment: How could the OP be wrong with that Avatar? :)

Answer (score 2):

Repeating what you did
$$f(x+h)=f(x)+h f'(x)+\frac{1}{2} h^2 f''(x)+\frac{1}{6} h^3 f^{(3)}(x)+O\left(h^4\right)$$
$$f\left(x+\frac{h}{2}\right)=f(x)+\frac{1}{2} h f'(x)+\frac{1}{8} h^2 f''(x)+\frac{1}{48} h^3
   f^{(3)}(x)+O\left(h^4\right)$$
$$f(x+h)-2f\left(x+\frac{h}{2}\right)+f(x)=\frac{1}{4} h^2 f''(x)+\frac{1}{8} h^3 f^{(3)}(x)+O\left(h^4\right)$$
$$\frac{f(x+h)-2f\left(x+\frac{h}{2}\right)+f(x) } {\frac {h^2}4}=f''(x)+\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}} h f^{(3)}(x)+O\left(h^{\color{red}{2}}\right)$$
$$\frac{f(x+h)-2f\left(x+\frac{h}{2}\right)+f(x) } {\frac {h^2}4}-f''(x)=\frac{1}{2} h f^{(3)}(x)+O\left(h^{2}\right)=O(h)$$ It cannot be $O(h^2)$ except if $f^{(3)}(x)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Nevertheless it’s true that
$$\lim_{h\to0} {{f(x_{0} + h ) - 2 f(x_{0} + h/2 ) +f(x_{0} )} \over {h^2 / 4}}=f’’(x_0), $$
as
$$f^{(n)}(x_0)=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{1}{t^n}
\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}f(x_0+kt).$$

From here we have only $O(h)$ in general. So there’s no need for lengthy calculations.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative (physicist's) way:

We know the expression on the left approximates the second derivative in the middle point to the second order:

$$\frac{f(x+h)-2f(x+h/2)+f(x)}{(h/2)^2}=f^{(2)}(x+h/2)+\mathcal{O}(h^2)$$
Your expression has an unknown remainder:
$$\frac{f(x+h)-2f(x+h/2)+f(x)}{(h/2)^2}=f^{(2)}(x)+\mathcal{O}(?)$$
Subtract and rearrange:

$$\mathcal{O}(?)=f^{(2)}(x+h/2)-f^{(2)}(x)+\mathcal{O}(h^2)$$
But the right hand side approximates the first derivative (of $f^{(2)}$) only linearly, by fundamental definition of the derivative (or first order Taylor series, if you want):
$$\mathcal{O}(?)=\left(f^{(3)}(x) \frac{\color{red}{h}}{2} + \mathcal{O}(h^2)\right)+\mathcal{O}(h^2)=\mathcal{O}(h)$$
You also get the correct third factor for the leading remainder term: $f'''(x)h/2$.